# How to extend the number of webhooks on Github

Tags: azure, github, webhooks, azure-web-app-service, automated-deploy

I am setting up automated deployment for my company Azure webapps except that we reached the github organization limit. As far as I know the limit is 20 and we do have 20 webhooks on github. I cannot find anything in their documentation about overcoming this limit, so my question is:

a) Has anyone faced this before ?
b) Is there any way to increase the limit or even to remove it ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could process the webhook in a separate app,  say https://github.com/atmos/heaven. What are the 20 destination webhooks?

Comment: There is Azure webhooks for continuous deployment, Slack and Appveyor.